# Is it possible to create a constrain with a union of two properties in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

Is it possible to create a constrain with a union of two properties. I have `address` and `chainId`. My constrain must assert that is possible to have only 1 node with an specific `address` and `chainId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can specify multiple properties when creating uniqueness constraints: CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:label) ASSERT n.property1, n.property2, ..., IS UNIQUE;
Source: https://memgraph.com/docs/fundamentals/constraints#uniqueness-constraint

For example, let's say I did:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Company) ASSERT n.address, n.chainId IS UNIQUE;
```

And then I went on and create companies:

```
CREATE (:Company {address: "Address 1", chainId: 1})

CREATE (:Company {address: "Address 1", chainId: 2})

CREATE (:Company {address: "Address 2", chainId: 1})

CREATE (:Company {address: "Address 2", chainId: 2})
```

This is okay because none of the pairs of (address, chainId) is not exactly the same.
But, if I try running the following query:

```
CREATE (:Company {address: "Address 1", chainId: 1})
```

I get

```
Unable to commit due to unique constraint violation on :Company(address, chainId)
```

as expected, because that pair of (address, chainId) already exists in the database.